# how can i make a selection on an image map?

Tags: php, html, multipleselection

http://magic.cardbinder.com/

I'm tinkering on my website... still learning.  I'd like to be able to make some selections on an image.  Specifically, I'd like to know how to choose up to 2 options in menuButtons.  So I can make a selection in cardChoice, then type something search, and narrow my results.

I'd like to make it so that if you click 2 of the buttons in menuButtons, it will make those selections in the database.  So on the second click, it's like hitting enter in the search box.

```
<div id="leftMenu">
<h1>CardBinder</h1>
<form name="mainMenu" action="cardChoice.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <select name="chooseSet">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
  <br/><img src="/menu.png" alt="Menu" usemap="#menuButtons" /> <br/><br/>
  <map name="menuButtons">
    <area shape="circle" coords="112,36,35" alt="White" href="/Mana/W.gif" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="189,93,35" alt="Blue" href="/Mana/U.gif" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="163,186,35" alt="Black" href="/Mana/B.gif" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="59,186,35" alt="Red" href="/Mana/R.gif" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="35,93,35" alt="Green" href="/Mana/G.gif" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="69,278,35" alt="Planeswalker" href="" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="149,278,35" alt="Creature" href="" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="34,347,35" alt="Enchantment" href="" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="111,347,35" alt="Artifact" href="" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="188,347,35" alt="Land" href="" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="74,413,35" alt="Instant" href="" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="153,413,35" alt="Sorcery" href="" />
  </map>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Card Name" size="20" maxlength="50" />
  </div>    
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: the hrefs on those buttons are just placeholders... testing to see if they went somewhere.

Comment: You could use jquery to trap the clicks on those map elements and toggle some image overlays for on/off selections, but a standard html-only image map does not allow multiple clicks. It's just basically the graphical equivalent of a bunch of `<a>` links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although image maps are still in the spec for html5, they can be incredibly difficult to match and they never seem to be aligned perfectly. 


If you enjoy web development and want to get better at it, I would suggest learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com).
It is really easy to learn and it should allow you to get around your image map problem with less pixel number crunching.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still very new, and all the different 'languages' are a bit scary.  I'm starting to see that each of them serve a pretty specific purpose.  I'll study jquery and see what I can't figure out!

Comment: Many things can be done with all languages. As far as the web languages, there are certain things they can do specifically. As a general rule HTML is used for layout, jQuery for anything that is dynamically changing your page, PHP for anything that has to run on a database or do manipulation on the server. There's more to it than that, but that will help you figure out what to search for.